# Can I apply to the same company again?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, new-job, applications

I had an onsite interview with a company that I really like one and half months ago. Unfortunately I wasn't able to do well in the interview ( I was really nervous as it was my first ever onsite interview ). I really worked hard in gaining the skills that I was missing.  Now the same company is coming to my college career fair again next week. Is it really suggestible to go and contact them again? If yes, can I say them that I had an interview with them previously? I am even ready to go to the company at my own cost if I am chosen for an onsite interview again. Please suggest me.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/should-employers-that-previously-rejected-me-be-contacted-again) which appears to be the exact same question?

Comment: Tell them you really want to work with them, you took time to gain skills specifically with that goal and you'd like another chance.  Unless they really didn't like you, I bet they'll be impressed enough with your motivation to give you that chance.