# Should I mention to have been previously "rejected"?

Tags: interviewing, career-development

Six months ago I was contacted via Linkedin and my website from a company for an interview, I did well but they were looking for someone more experienced to manage 4-5 people around the globe.

(yes, I know, they read my cv and contacted me anyway. It was funny when he asked me "Why are you looking for a job?" "Actually you called me".)

Anyway, in my actual company, a small consultant one, the work is not so exciting and since I'm just 24 I'm looking for something more dynamic, like the company that contacted me.

I found out that the first company is member of a "campus" of exciting companies, like a little Silicon Valley (spinning class, green area and stuff like that). One of them is looking for a position that fits me more (I hope).

Should I mention that I've been already interviewed from someone from their group and that I'm there for the amazing environment that I've found?

Comment: Very [related question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2154/2322)

Comment: First, you weren't rejected. Second, in the interview (if you get that far), it should naturally come up when they ask you something like "So why are you applying for this position?" (Or "to our company?) The fact that you know a fair bit about the company and your interest goes back before your current application is a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you definately should. Honesty is always the best policy.

Plus, from the way you have described it, you are not re-applying for the same job you were rejected for previously. You were obviously not rejected as being unsuitable for the company as a whole (culture, approach etc) but for a fairly specific role based on a specific lack of experience)

If anything, because THEY contacted you, I would mention it. It shows that you have been on thier radar before

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think that I should mention it also in the email for the application or that would be "too much"?

Comment: Personally, I would say that was too much. I would leave it until the face to face interview. As to how you bring it up, they will probably ask you "what do you know about us/the company" and that would be the most natural time to bring it up

Answer (score 0):

This is more common than you think with recruiters for companies.  It is likely a different recruiter who found your skills or resume a good match.  If they do keep a log of past interviewees, sometimes they don't check that.

I would mention it casually, but just as an FYI and not as a deterrent.  Express your interest in moving forward and let them decide how to proceed with all the info.  Chances are they have a new role to fill and you're a qualified candidate again.