# In US federal job qualifications, can "one year of specialized experience" be spread across multiple years of work?

Tags: united-states, work-experience, qualification, government

A lot of listings at USAJobs.gov have a section that starts like this:

> **Minimum Qualifications** 
>   Specialized Experience: One year of specialized experience which includes (list of tasks)

If I do those things as 25% of my job for 4 years, does that count?

An answer specific to [General Schedule position qualifications](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/classification-qualifications/general-schedule-qualification-standards/) would be preferred, but perhaps the standards for US state or local jobs would be comparable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it critical that you meet every requirement of a job you're applying for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/is-it-critical-that-you-meet-every-requirement-of-a-job-youre-applying-for)

Comment: Only the employer can tell you that for sure, but [this proposed duplicate](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/is-it-critical-that-you-meet-every-requirement-of-a-job-youre-applying-for) should tell you to not take this number too seriously.

Comment: The fact that this is a US federal job posting does mean that requirements like this will be taken more strictly than at many private sector employers - something to keep in mind when comparing to those potential duplicate questions.

Comment: At the end of the day, this will entirely depend on the manager, responsible for choosing the application provided you get to their desk.  Nobody but those responsible for making that decision, can answer this question.  The applications will “racked and stacked” and the highest scoring applications will be forwarded to the manager.

Answer (score 10):

It would depend on the skill and the exact duty, but if you've been doing a job for 4 years that requires you to do it even for 25% of the time, I'd call that 4 years of experience, and emphasize you have 4 years.

The hiring manager might have different ideas, but it's up to you to sell it.