# Victim of callous screening

Tags: interviewing, pre-screening

I have had this terrible experience twice in my life both while attending interviews as a developer for reputed MNC software firm . Even after shortlisting my resume for the interviews and after clearing successfully countless rounds of interviews , it ends up in the HR round where the HR says that I don't have enough relevant experience for the position in question . I wonder if that is the case then it should have been sorted out while screening , and not after the candidate has appeared , slogged and cleared so many rounds of interviews . It frustrating and demoralizing , but is there any way to deal with this ?

Comment: Are you really saying you interview with a company for "countless rounds" and *then* have an HR interview which they ask about your experience for the first time in the process?

Comment: [This question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/how-can-i-overcome-years-of-experience-requirements-when-applying-to-positions) basically is the same problem.

Comment: They knew my experience from the beginning , just that the reason they framed for not on-boarding me was that my experience is not enough !

Comment: We could edit your question to make it constructive and on topic but that question becomes the dupe of the question linked by Enderland.

Comment: The reason given is not necessarily the reason you were not chosen but it is the offical position of the MNC and its affiliates.  The actual reason is that you did not meet some arbitrary feelie goodie of the decision maker so that they would be willing to overlook your lack or experience.

Comment: @NoobUnChained It's possible they were actually interested in you, but decided in the end to hire someone else, and just used the "lack of experience" as an excuse to explain why they didn't choose you.

Comment: Interviews are a competition, the unpalatable truth is that someone else did better than you did in the interviews and likely that person had more experience than you do as well. I've had interviews where I was sure I got the job and was not selected and others where I was very surprised to be selected. It all depends on who else they are interviewing as well as your own performance. All you can do is improve your own interviews, but there will still be some jobs where someone beats you in the interview. That's just how life is.

Comment: When a company is having a tough time finding the "right-person", they will frequently take a chance on talking to someone with less experience but whose resume indicates other factors that they like. However, if after talking to that person and the other factors don't wow them or at least alleviate the apprehensions they have about the lack of experience, then it boils down to "a lack of experience". Would you rather have them say "You didn't WOW us!"? If you are interviewing over your head then you need to have a plan and message that alleviates the employer's fears going into that interview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HR people were not the people who concluded that your experience was not sufficient. It was the people who interviewed you. HR people and the software used scan resumes only look for the key words in your resume, and pass it on to the pool of candidates worth interviewing.

Since you weren't in the interviews with the other candidates, you have now idea how their experience or interview compared to yours.

You're frustrated to be so close to getting what you wanted, and being rejected. Don't let that frustration make the decision on what company you interview with. You try again later or for a different position.

(The only time you wouldn't try again is if they offered you a job and you rejected it. Company's don't like being jerked around either.)