# Employer has changed offer after I already accepted

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I got a job offer from a reputable company that I have accepted after negotiating with the technical manager who I will be reporting to. Strangely, I got a call today from the HR telling me that there was miscommunication between them and the technical manager: they informed him that I have 7 years experience rather than 4. Although they still need my services, they will have to reduce the offer.

I requested some time to think about the new offer. Now it's okay for me to accept the new offer especially since it's a well-known company and I will gain a lot of experience, but this miscommunication makes me hesitant to accept it and I'm afraid that I will give them the indication that I'm cheap.

---

Thanks to all; I really didn't expect all these answers and help. I decided to refuse the offer.

Comment: Hi Selem, welcome to the Workplace! I think you have the basis of a good question here, but you are likely to get some close votes since you are simply asking "What should I do?" Take a look at our [guidelines](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically why we don't like to give advice for ["what do I do"questions](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2695#2695). Consider [editing](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/43733/edit) to rephrase your question.

Comment: is the new offer acceptable to you?  Are you willing to walk away over the diffence? We can help you negotiate but we need these details to do so.

Comment: Not sure everyone would say its "OK" for this to happen

Comment: You were offered compensation package A; you negotiated compensation package B; now the want to to accept compensation package C. Where does C fill in the range of A to B?

Comment: If they still need your services, then they can pay what they had offered.  Otherwise they don't really need your services.  The risk of this being an underhanded negotiation tactic is enough I would walk if they don't honor the original offer.

Comment: The hiring manager may have been given the wrong information (which was their fault and not yours), but he still interviewed you and believed based on the interview that you were fully capable of filling the position. There will be a probation period anyway where they can find out if you are not capable. On the other hand, if you accept, your personnel file will contain the word "mug" or "doormat" in big red letters, and forget about any raise in the next years.

Comment: Do you mean that you have 4 years' experience and they mistakenly thought you had 7, or you have 7 years' experience and they're now offering as if you only had 4?

Comment: If nothing else, you should tell them you expect (in writing, as part of the contract) a yearly raise of 1/3 the difference between the two offers over the next three years so that by the time you have 7 years experience, you're making at least what they initially offered. :-)

Comment: In your case, 4 or 7 years experience does not matter. They interviewed you and deemed you fit for the position. They were prepared to pay you the initial offer for filling that position. The position nor its tasks have changed, neither should the salary.

Comment: I would request that they improve on their initial offer, and otherwise go elsewhere.

Comment: First of all, have a look around to understand if it's an issue with the company. There are website that collects opinion on companies from the employee. Check if anybody is complaining on similar issues. If they pass the first step, make them understand, in a kind way, that it was their mistake, not yours. They should stick to the original offer.

Comment: Do they want to hire you in at a lower level or the same level just lower pay? At a big company, your level matters a lot. It sets the minimal expectations. I worked with a guy who came in 1 level higher than he should have. His reviews were terrible, despite his work would have been satisfactory if he was one level lower. He eventually was forced out of the company. Once your reputation is tarnished, it is hard to recover. Being hired into a position you aren't qualified to perform will certainly tarnish your reputation.

Comment: I'd take what's offered now (can't hurt to have another bullet point on the CV) and keep applying to greater and better positions. You don't need to be fired to be looking for a job :)

Comment: I agree with most everyone here. What really bothers me, though, is the assumption that the years experience matters to begin with. Either you're right for the job, or you're not. The number of years experience between 4 and 7 is such a generic variable to peg salary to that I'd question this company as a whole in regards to their hiring practices. I want to hire the right person...whether they have 4 vs. 7 years experience is of no concern to me. What matter is the *kind* of experience a candidate has and what they learned from said experience.

Comment: So they're claiming that their HR department is incompetent, they supposedly told the hiring manager you had more experience than you did, and that they now have to reduce an offer that's already been made and accepted? Good thing you know what they're like before you start there. Run Away Fast.

Comment: Mistakes like this do happen. But whether they were honest mistakes or not, you should insist on the original offer for your own sake.

Comment: If the HR department isn't run by a red cat, then it may well be a mistake. Otherwise, like Bob Jarvis said, Run Away Fast.

Comment: **I have faced the same situation two weeks ago with exact same words, I wonder if they are still pulling this trick** It was a very sad experience, I have tried to negotiate but the rate is fixed and I have not received any offer.

Comment: Sounds like the company should be named on Glassdoor. Then, perhaps employees who took the offer can compare notes.

Comment: Maybe you should ask them if you could run the HR department. I would refuse the offer. They seem to be talking around the bush. Doesn't sound like a good start to me.

Comment: Is there a problem with just pretending the original offer was not made?

Answer (score 151):

Unless you misled HR during an interview about something that would affect starting salary, you need to take a long, hard look at this company.

This could be a **bait-and-switch** tactic used by the company to get applicants to agree to a lower salary.  Even if its an honest mistake, its a pretty egregious one - they extended an offer and you accepted, now they're reneging on their promise.

They've already screwed up the offer, what if they screw up the start date?

Comment: +1.  Even if there were a 90% chance it was an innocent mistake, I just wouldn't trust them enough to sign on, unless as an act of desperation.  They might mess up the payroll or something like that further down the road, and businesses that don't generally stay on top of things are just not the kind of thing you would want to entangle yourself with.

Comment: @Panzercrisis - money isn't innocent.  Even if reality says that 90% of these incidents are innocent, the employee will not ever believe it was so.

Comment: I just meant a 90% chance perceived for the individual case.  In general, it would actually surprise me slightly if this were innocent, but I wouldn't jump to conclusions either.

Comment: Right. If, as an employer, my firm had made this error, then I'd still consider the offer we'd already made to be binding (on us).

Comment: bait and switch afaik is never a tactic but really fraudulent. what's wrong with an honest tactic? it's part of the game.

Answer (score 70):

Mistakes do happen, but you should clarify how the change affects the job you've been offered.

If they are paying you as 4 years experience, does that mean a difference in the role, or are you doing the same job but just being paid less?

If the role is different, get a new role spec and see if this is where you are wanting to go. If it's just less money, I would be pushing back, you'll have the same expectations on you once you are in the job as if you had the 7 years to start.

Comment: The role spec might not be different  - but I would expect some difference in the support/supervision required for people in that role with different experience so there would be a consideration in salary. That said - if someone proves they can work without that supervision, they should get a pay rise pretty quick.

Answer (score 58):

I find their excuse implausible.  At least two people in the company screwed up: the HR person *and* the hiring manager.  Did the hiring manager not get a copy of your resumé and review it when interviewing?  Was the interview done carelessly, in a way that didn't let you adequately prove your skills or ask you about your experience?  It's not just a simple matter of miscommunication — their sloppy hiring process is also suspect.

Consider the awkwardness of working there if you simply accept their lower offer.  You'll be working for a manager who knows that you are exploitable, and that is an impression that can never go away for as long as you work for that manager.  If you want to work there, you must at least negotiate a salary that exceeds their reduced offer, or a signing bonus.

Were you interviewed by other team members?  Did you get their business cards?  (I usually ask for them.)  Consider asking other employees about the company culture (not necessarily mentioning this specific incident), to gauge whether this is a sign of a pattern of how they operate.

Comment: "At least two people in the company screwed up: the HR person and the hiring manager." Is it so inconceivable that two people would make a mistake?

Comment: @2rs2ts They screwed up in different ways, though. The HR person might have made a simple typo or swapped two dossiers. The hiring manager, though, should have had a verbatim copy of the candidate's résumé available, and furthermore, had a responsibility to assess the candidate's claims of experience using independent means.

Comment: @2rs2ts: As a company owner, if anyone on my staff made this mistake I would insist that they follow through on the original offer.  That's integrity.  Even if both people screwed up, backing up like this is bad for the business.

Answer (score 21):

There are three approaches:

1. Accept. Mistakes happen, and it's still a good offer.
2. Reject. If they screwed up something that important -- intentionally or not -- you don't want to work there.
3. Negotiate.

I suggest the last one. You have a strong position, and can put the ball in their court. Tell them "Your initial offer is closer to what I expected. I can accept that, but not the new offer."

- If it was intentional (a bait-and-switch), they won't do anything, and you dodged a bullet.
- If it was a mistake, they may be willing to own up it. They're a bit embarrassed right now, and a matter-of-fact "um, no" may work.

I'd be surprised if you couldn't get something out of this situation better than their second offer.

Comment: I agree, the problem is, now you are starting at the previously agreed upon offer, and they have already told you that it is a walk away point for them, whatever you get will be lower.

Comment: @kleineg, nowhere was it described as "a walk away point for them".

Comment: They tried to quote a lower figure, saying the one they previously set was not acceptable, you can't negotiate up from there, so it basically becomes the new ceiling.

Comment: @kleineg, are you sure that is "not acceptable", or is it "not desirable"? You might be right, but I don't there is conclusive proof from the description.

Comment: The person saying the previously agreed upon salary not acceptable is not the OP but the company. The OP and company came to an agreement, and then the company said that they would not hire the OP at that salary. That gives you their walk away, they will not hire the OP at that salary. Heck with the OP renegotiating for more, they will not get the original agreement. The only place they can go is down. I agree with the choices you presented, but the OP will not get the salary they previously negotiated, it has been taken off the table.

Comment: @kleineg, that is we where we differ. I believe the only place they can go is up. I certainly agree there is a good chance they will not get the salary they previously negotiated, but they might get closer. Or maybe not. The fact that the company made a mistake puts the OP in a strong position.

Comment: Yes, possibly up from what the second offer was. No, not up from the original offer.

Comment: Answer this. Will the OP get more than what they previously agreed to?

Answer (score 11):

It's unfortunate, and highly unprofessional of them, but mistakes do happen. If it is not an honest mistake, then you should probably decline their offer and find someplace else to work. You don't want to work in a place that plays silly games.

But if it is an honest mistake, and you really want this opportunity, you may not want to walk away from it over this situation. Your question didn't say whether you agreed that the original offer was high and the new offer was more in line with what you expect for four years of experience (factoring in that working there, including pay, needs to still be an improvement over your current situation in order to be attractive).

Consider what might happen if you were to demand they honor their first offer. They may rescind it, leaving you without the opportunity you seek to have. Or they may honor the first offer, but will place high expectations on you, and very likely limit your pay increases for a few years to bring your pay back in line with your years of experience. Large companies use formulas for determining pay within a certain band. If you start at the top of a band, your pay won't be able to grow as much until you get promoted to a new position in the next band.

In the end, it's up to you to decide whether this is an honest mistake, and if you want to forgive them for it. They will not think poorly of you for accepting the lower (more correct) offer if it was an honest mistake.

Comment: Probably the only way to really know if it's an honest mistake would be to start working there and be watchful for a pattern of manipulation and exploitation. If the culture of this company is bad, you will find out soon enough. Be ready to move on if necessary.

Comment: It's better to have a higher initial salary and no raises than to expect several years of salary raises before you get back up to the same initial salary level.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham You can probably get a good feel for the company culture just visiting the actual work space and chatting for 20 minutes with some current employees in the same/similar roles. A crappy company usually has crappy workspaces, and/or horror stories from the employees.

Comment: @MartinCarney but what if the current employees have no permission to tell these horror stories to strangers?

Comment: IMO it's highly improbable that this is an "honest mistake". The company has a financial incentive to get a new hire to accept a lower offer. Frankly this makes the company come across as either incompetent or slimeballs. Either way, run away!

Comment: @MartinCarney I went for an interview once, and on my way out via the restroom an employee basically told me to save myself. I wonder though - if it was so bad, why were they still working there?

Comment: @gbjbaanb I've had a similar experience at a company that collapsed three weeks after I started working there. Most likely they are staying until they found a new job - better to be paid at a crappy job than not to be paid at all.

Answer (score 8):

If they've already made you an offer, presumably they're satisfied that you have the skills they're looking for.  They should be paying you on the basis of your skills, not the amount of time it took you to acquire them.  A company that uses the number of years of your experience for any purpose other than pre-interview screening is automatically highly suspect.  Do they also give raises and promotions based on seniority rather than skill?  If you accept this offer, not only are you selling yourself short, but you may find yourself pulling the dead weight of a bunch of incompetents who are getting paid more than you.

Comment: You imply that only skills matter, and experience doesn't. That's not quite true. Experience — the accumulated result of observing mistakes made by yourself and your colleagues — can provide wisdom that can't be taught. There is a difference between a 1000-hour pilot and a 6000-hour pilot, even if they have the exact same certifications. The 6000-hour pilot has seen more stuff go not according to plan, and is likely to react better to certain unusual situations. The same goes for other fields, such as software development. Experience is something that employers are willing to pay for.

Comment: @200_success People gain experience at such widely varying rates that demonstrable skills are the only useful metric.  Employee A might gain more experience in one year than Employee B gains in five.  I don't know about pilots, but this is definitely true in the field of software development.

Comment: Agreed. "4 years instead of 7" should affect things like whether you get invited to interview in the first place. By the time they've interviewed and tested you, it should be irrelevant.

Comment: I agree with 200_success. I can claim a list of skills and even talk about them all in expert detail having only read about them in textbooks. I still wouldn't make as good of an employee as someone with the same list of skills and twice the number of years applying them in practice.

Comment: @talrnu If the interview consists of trivia questions, that's another problem with the interview process.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Short of a long, intensive working interview, it's difficult to accurately gauge someone's working knowledge of their skillset during any type of interview process. It's easier, and probably more accurate, to guess at that based on the number of verifiable years they've practiced those skills in the wild.

Comment: @talrnu Nonsense.  In my field, for example, an interviewer could tell far more about a candidate by examining some software they've written or, better yet, the source code.  As I've said, their number of years of experience is an *extremely* unreliable predictor of anything.  (And for that matter, so is their formal education.)

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Demonstrating previous work might help someone with less experience prove their competence, but that does nothing to disprove the fact that more years with the same skills is far more likely to indicate a higher-quality worker. And what if it's difficult or impossible to demonstrate past work (e.g. the code or even software itself is unavailable to review)? Would you really hire a newbie web developer over a veteran at the same salary if the former could point you to a public website to demo their work and the latter couldn't?

Comment: @talrnu Yes, in a heartbeat.

Comment: @talrnu: Absolutely, without a second thought (assuming, of course, that it was a *good* demo). Regarding the other question, then ask the interviewee to create a simple example code that you can look through. I was just asked to do the same.

Comment: @200_success you could also refer a [fantastic explanation over here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1485/168 "How can I overcome “years of experience” requirements when applying to positions?") "You can be highly skilled but lack the experience to know when to apply that skill... Judgement comes not from success, but from failures. Most companies want to hire people that have had their failures paid for by previous companies..."

Answer (score 1):

"It's a well known company.... experience..."

If it's that well-known of a company, it's probably run by executives using the same bait and switch / exploitative employment tactics as others like facbeook, google, microsoft at this point, etc.

*don't mislead yourself into taking a position for the experience.*

A job at Microsoft is still just a job, and you'll be huddled up in a cube the same as any other.

In reality, you should examine your feeling that you can accept less wages to work at this company solely because of their brand, as this is the result of a very complex marketing campaign lead by this and other companies.

*Oh, you're going to be working here! Do it for the glory! Do it for the fame! Do it for anything but the money.*

It takes less money to pay media outlets to glorify your company, persistently, over the years, than it does to pay good wages to thousands of employees. So stories like this one are very common among applicants of well known organizations. They have thousands of slots to fill.... If they can shave even 1%,3%,15% off the salaries of 1000 people coming in.... that adds up to a ton of money, that they can use to create other positions.

In short, I doubt they mistook your 4 years of experience for 7. They might have a shady recruiter that did this because they wanted commission, but the hiring manager would have seen your resume, and HR probably did too when they made the offer, if it was so dependent on experience.

Something I've realized over the years, and this is more of a concept in other countries than the US, but is becoming more common, is that some people will negotiate until the very end. It doesn't matter *what* they're saying when they're coming back to you with this - it's a negotiating tactic.

**If they were able to offer you that money "at 7 years experience", then you know they have the budget for that much money for that position. End of story. I would say you're willing to accept at that originally offered rate, otherwise you will continue looking elsewhere. Do not accept anything else,** they will likely either cave, or it will be a position where other shady things will have happened later on and you can be glad you didn't let yourself get taken advantage of by management **BEFORE EVEN STARTING THE JOB.**

Imagine the mind games that would follow later on.

^ Additionally, this may be a filtering technique. ***Maybe they're only wanting to hire people they can manipulate like this.***

And depending on the amount of the change... Say it's $5k/year. Maybe $10k/year. A company should be able to overlook that slip up anyways. It's an amount of money that, when looking at a department level, etc, is more or less a rounding error.

A company wouldn't throw away a good candidate because of a mistake *they* made when hiring them. Not a good one anyways. I could see perhaps them doing it if they had concerns about someone making more than someone of the opposite sex with the same qualifications.... but even then. I think you should avoid this company.

The amount they pay the recruiter that found you for this organization, for example, is likely above $20,000, (or perhaps 20-25% of the salary for the position). So quibbling over small amounts (really, anything under ~10k / year or so) would seem petty on their part

Answer (score -3):

I get the impression that you haven't actually signed anything or officially begun employment. Unless you've already begun employment, they're under no obligation to honor their original offer. Likewise, even after accepting their offer, you could change your mind and walk away before signing anything.

I would completely forget about their original offer and consider the new offer as if it was the only offer they've made. How does this new offer compare to offers from other companies? Are you comfortable with their valuation of your experience? Is this new offer the best option for you?

I say you should completely forget their original offer, but I do make one exception: remember how much they were willing to pay you for 7 years of experience so that 3 years from now (when you actually do have 7 years of experience) you can use that information to negotiate a raise. If you're not making as much in 3 years as they were originally willing to offer you under the assumption you were joining the company with that much experience, then you will probably want to look for alternate employment at that time. Sure, the economy or the company's financial stability may change, but half of your experience will also be with this company by then, so I'd say their offer should be treated as the minimum acceptable salary in 3 years' time.

Comment: I woud get it in writing that I would get at least the orginal offer after attaining 3 more years of experience. I would expect to get 1/3 of the differnece every year until it was made up.  If it was an honest mistake, they should have no problem with that.

Comment: @HLGEM The problem with that approach is you're locking yourself into that track for the next 3 years. What if the company does very well and you could have gotten more lucrative raises naturally without such a contract? The odds that their offer to a newcomer is as good as the salary they pay a third-year employee with the same experience are pretty low, so you'd probably just be shooting yourself in the foot with an agreement like that.

Comment: I disagree. Pay raises of 2-3 % are the most common, so if he has a bigger gap, he should ensure that he gets to that level.

Comment: @HLGEM If in three years' time the new guy with comparable skills and experience to yours is getting paid more on his first day than you are after all of that time with the company, then it's more likely you're just not doing a good job. But I guess you could rely on a contract if you're not good or dedicated enough to earn your raises.

Comment: @talmu, keep your illusions. I have frequently seen people with less experience and who are not top performers get hired for more than existing employees make because they are in the marketplace. You have much less leverage to get a big raise when you are already an employee. The only way to get a large raise at most companies is to get promoted or to put in your notice.

Comment: @HLGEM I'm living the illusion - my salary has increased 50% in two years because I work hard, make my value obvious, and communicate with my boss so we both know what we want from each other. If I signed a contract that limited my pay increase to 10% I'd have been an idiot. If my case is unusual, it's not because of my circumstances, it's because the average worker's standards and self valuation are too low.

Answer (score -3):

Take the job and use them as a stepping stone. Who says you have to stay? Sometimes you have to play the fool to fool the fool who thinks they are fooling you. Always accept if it's better than what you have then work like hell to leave with a  glowing reputation. Companies aren't  going to be loyal to you anyway. The days of being in one place and retiring are over. So stick and move!

Answer (score -5):

Walk away an accepted offer is an contract and if the company wont stand behind the offer then well that is a company to avoid.

How did you accept if its in writing rather than verbaly then the company is breaking their contract with you.

As you accepted an offer I would demand payment for the breach of contract on pain of legal action - say 3 months salary.

Comment: This advice is not realistic. Are you suggesting OP hire a lawyer over this? A lawsuit over this matter, even a "threatened" lawsuit, will cause the company to rescind the offer, which is completely within the bounds of the contract.

Comment: @KentAnderson the company has already burned any relationship and committed breach of contract I would defiantly imply that I was going to the lawyers in order to get a compromise agreement.

Comment: Lawyering up in order to get the job? If OP is worried about his reputation within the company for accepting an adjusted offer, imagine what his reputation will be if he sues them, wins, and then starts working there. That's one of the worst ways I can think of to start a relationship. I agree that the company has made a mistake and OP would be justified in walking away from it, should he decide that's the best course of action. But suing over just a few thousand dollars' difference (at best) is not good advice.

Comment: @KentAnderson the job is toast at this point - get what you can and move on

Comment: Taking legal action over something like this will certainly kill any future chances with this company and potentially many other ones as well. Word gets around and that's a sure fire way to end up on the "do not hire list"

Comment: @Hilmar that's why you use a compromise agreement

Comment: While this depends on location, in most cases in the US all but the very highest jobs are at-will, so even if they agree to pay you X they can change that the next day for any reason or for no reason.  Lawsuit will get you absolutely nothing.  Unless this is a union job or a very high ranking (officer of the company or at least VP) it's almost certainly not enforceable.

Comment: Neither side signed a thing (if they did, you would be correct), that means they are free to renege and so are you and the only things at stake are your reputations. You cannot litigate a verbal agreement.

Comment: A lawsuit isn't totally out of the question here if he suffered damages because he relied on the rescinded offer. Because the employment offer was presumably "at-will", he can't claim lost wages from the rescinded job. However some jurisdictions will, under the theory of promissory estoppel, allow him to claim other damages as a result of the reliance: http://labor-employment-law.lawyers.com/job-hunting/promises-and-rescinded-job-offers.html

Comment: @kleineg actually a verbal agreement is a contract harder to prove than a written one I give you

Comment: Good luck having a good reputation in any city with this type of behavior.