# Can I put fake experience in different skills than I am working in?

Tags: job-search, resume, work-experience

I have been working as a PHP developer for 2 years. Now, I want to switch to Java. I have gone through a course on udemy.com , and also some DSA. If I update my resume as 1.5 years of Java Experience, rather than PHP,  will this be considered as fraud ?

Comment: Fraud is being dishonest in order to secure some benefit for yourself. Maybe you can figure this one out for yourself.

Comment: see also: [How can I overcome "years of experience" requirements when applying to positions?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1485/168)

Comment: **"Can I lie?"** - You can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Suppose you are hired with fake experience on your resume. Then, very quickly, your employer will find out that you can't do the job, and they will fire you. What do you really gain here ? It is better to list your real experience on the resume, and find the jobs that fit your skills for long term employment.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is a lie, and it's singularly bad idea to lie in a resume.

Answer (score 4):

I interviewed a candidate who listed a fairly obscure programming language on their resume. This is probably the most difficult programming language I have ever encountered and requires some serious mind-bending even for the simplest task. Unfortunately for them: I've done this mind bending and after two or three question it was very clear that they didn't.

I blocked them from being hired and I put them on the permanent blacklist. I don't work with liars.

It was also stupid: the skill was not required for the job. There was little to gain and a lot to loose by being dishonest.

Answer (score 3):

It's never a good choice to misrepresent yourself in your resume.  How long do you think it will take someone to determine that you really don't have 1.5 years of Java experience but simply took a udemy course?

Or let's say you do get the job and now you have little idea of how to do things.  Might they investigate your claims and find out you lied?  What good (for you) could come of this?  Most likely you will be let go and now you have no job.

Be honest and accurate about your qualifications.  Be up-front and say "I've been developing with PHP for the last two years but I'd really like to extend my experience to include Java.  I took a udemy course and really got into it."

Most good companies look for people who are ambitious and are able to learn new skills and technologies.  Those things are difficult to teach.  Tools are just tools and you can be a "Java coder" after going to a boot camp.